# GCP Tomcat java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

Tags: java, python, flask, tomcat, google-cloud-platform

Situation:
This issue occurs when REST API call is made from ReactJS/nginx. Then Java/Tomcat makes another REST API call to Python/Flask server. The response from Flask is sent to ReactJS by Tomcat.

```
Call flow:
Receive REST API call from ReactJS to Java/Tomcat (){
  response = send REST API from Java/Tomcat to python/Flask();
  return response;
}
```

The following error occurs when Rest API (*http://localhost:5000/adb/killserver/1234*) is sent from GCP VM based Java client code to python flask based server.

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:556)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1226)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1162)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1056)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:990)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1570)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at com.example.APKGeneration.restapi.MyGETRequest(restapi.java:35)
    at com.example.APKGeneration.APKGeneration.sendGetMessage(APKGeneration.java:423)
    at com.example.APKGeneration.APKGeneration.killADBRest(APKGeneration.java:433)
    at com.example.APKGeneration.APKGeneration.executeTestcases(APKGeneration.java:113)
    at com.example.Common.design.onClickBtnTestExecutionState(design.java:523)
    at com.digitran.vte.MyResource.ExecuteTestsAndSaveInMongoDB(MyResource.java:1062)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:387)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:331)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1030)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:373)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.digitran.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:27)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at psiprobe.Tomcat90AgentValve.invoke(Tomcat90AgentValve.java:35)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The Java client code is given below:

```
public static StringBuffer MyGETRequest(String getUrlString) throws IOException {
        URL urlForGetRequest = new URL(getUrlString);
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        String readLine = null;
        HttpURLConnection conection = (HttpURLConnection) urlForGetRequest.openConnection();
        conection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        int responseCode = conection.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(conection.getInputStream()));         
            while ((readLine = in .readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(readLine);
            } in .close();
            // print result
            System.out.println("JSON String Result " + response.toString());
            //GetAndPost.POSTRequest(response.toString());
        } else {
            System.out.println("GET NOT WORKED");
        }
        return response;
    }
```

The python flask code is given below:

```
@app.route('/adb/killserver/<uuid>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def adbkillserver(uuid):
    print("You are getting adb kill-server request")
    command = "adb kill-server"
    result = run_command(command)
    print("result = ",result)
    return "adb kill server called"
```

Both Java and Python codes are working fine when deployed with WSL, Tomcat and War environment.

But not working when deployed in GCP, Tomcat and War environment.

In GCP, firewall is opened for ports 8080(Java) and 5000 (python).

Questions:

1. Is this error related to GCP firewall settings?
2. Is this error related to CORS?
3. Why it is working in WSL environment? but not in GCP?
4. Please provide solution for this issue.

Comment: I'm Not familiar with GCP, but are you sure both the Java and Python processes run on the same host? Asking because you invoke the Python endpoint at localhost.

Comment: ReactJS/nginx is running on GCP 1st VM. Java/Tomcat is running on GCP 2nd VM. Python/Flask is running on localhost.

Comment: The domain 'localhost' does not resolve to a globally unique host, other than, say, 'google.com'. Instead, if you want to connect a network client to some network ressource that is deployed on the same host as the client, you configure the client to use localhost. So, I assume, in your first scenario, you have all three services running on the same machine (your dev machine?) Then, in your non-working scenario, you have the three services distributed on different machines. Thus, if you configure Tomcat to connect to localhost:5000, it will look for that very service on GCP 2nd VM.

Comment: Thanks. it makes sense. I tried with ip address of my PC. But no luck. String getUrlString = "http://192.168.0.103:5000/adb/killserver/1234";

Comment: Your PC is not directly connected to the internet but instead to a network router which in turn is the gateway to the internet. Use a service like whatismyip.com to find out the current IP of your router (your provider usually does not assign a fixed IP, so be prepared that it's going to change on a daily basis.) Some routers offer port forwarding, so you could in principle expose your Flask/Python service to the internet. Note, however, that this may have severe security implications. Why don't you consider deploying the Flask/Python service to a third GCP VM?

Comment: Thanks. Because local PC is connected to Android device to handle ADB commands.